# Creating an object with another object as parameters in constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor

So i'm making a program that will find all the possible words (as defined by a dictionary) of a game of boggle (google it if you don't know what it is). Anyway i've got 3 classes/objects: a dictionary, a gameboard, and the bogglegame. the bogglegame is supposed to combing the dictionary and gameboard and find all the legal words. my constructor for bogglegame looks like

`BoggleGame::BoggleGame(Dictionary dictionaryIN, GameBoard gameboardIN)`

and the contsrtuctors for the Dictionary and GameBoard look like

`Dictionary::Dictionary(set<string> wordsInDictionaryIN, unsigned maxLengthIN)`
`GameBoard::GameBoard(vector<vector<string> > gamestateIN, unsigned boardSizeIN)`

when I try to compile i get an error that says "error: no matching function for call to ‘Dictionary::Dictionary()"

i'd like to be able to pass in the dictionary and gameboard objects into the constructor from main and store them as private members of the BoggleGame object effectively making the BoggleGame object an object of 2 objects.

EDIT: POSTING CODE

Constructor for BoggleGame

```
#include "BoggleGame.h"

BoggleGame::BoggleGame(Dictionary dictionaryIN, GameBoard gameboardIN)
{
    dictionary = dictionaryIN;
    gameboard = gameboardIN;
}
```

---

```
#pragma once

#include "Dictionary.h"
#include "GameBoard.h"

class BoggleGame
{
public:
    BoggleGame(Dictionary dictioanryIN, GameBoard gameboardIN);
    void foundWord(string wordIN);
    string findTheWords(string w, unsigned row, unsigned column);
    set<string> getTheFoundWords() {return foundWords;}
    bool isInDictionary(string word);
    bool isOffBoard(unsigned row, unsigned column);
    bool usedTile(unsigned row, unsigned column);
    vector<vector<string> > getTheGameBoard(){gameboard.getGameBoard();}

private:
    Dictionary dictionary;
    GameBoard gameboard;
    set<string> foundWords;
};
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using std::set;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary(set<string> wordsInDictionaryIN, unsigned maxLengthIN);
    bool isInDictionary(string wordIN);
    void foundWord (string wordIN);
    string findTheWords(string w, unsigned row, unsigned column);
    unsigned getMaxLength() {return maxLength;}

private:
    set<string> wordsInDictionary;
    unsigned maxLength;
    set<string> foundWords;

};
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

class GameBoard
{
public:
    GameBoard(vector<vector<string> > gamestateIN, unsigned boardSizeIN);
    bool outOfBoard(unsigned row, unsigned column);
    bool getTileUseState(unsigned row, unsigned column){return usedTiles.at(row).at(column);}
    void setTileUsed(unsigned row, unsigned column);
    vector<vector<string> > getGameBoard(){return gamestate;}
    unsigned getSize(){return boardSize;}
    vector<vector<bool> > getUsedTiles() {return usedTiles;}
    string readTile(unsigned row, unsigned column) {return gamestate.at(row).at(column);}
    void previousState(vector<vector<bool> > previous) {usedTiles = previous;}

private:
    vector<vector<string> > gamestate;
    vector<vector<bool> > usedTiles;
    unsigned boardSize;
};
```

Comment: Can you post the line that gives the error?

Comment: You are trying calling the default ctor somewhere (whatever line `Dictionary::Dictionary()` is referring to) but you have a user-defined ctor, so it suppresses the generation of the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in the constructor for `BoggleGame`. You don't have a default constructor for `Dictionary`. You can instead use an initialization list in your constructor:

```
BoggleGame::BoggleGame(Dictionary _dictionary)
    : dictionary{_dictionary}
```

Alternatively, provide a default constructor for `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary() = default;
Dictionary() { }
```

---

The reason the error occurs is because `dictionary` is default-constructed. When you assign your new value to `dictionary`, you're using the copy assignment operator. By using a constructor initialization list, you initialize `dictionary` directly. To demonstrate:

```
BoggleGame::BoggleGame(Dictionary _dictionary)
{
    dictionary = _dictionary;
}

Default.
Copy assignment.

BoggleGame::BoggleGame(Dictionary _dictionary)
    : dictionary{_dictionary}
    {
    }

Copy constructor.
```

Big difference as you can see.

Comment: and if this works i assume a similar thing for GameBoard? i also get the same error for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the way you declare your Dictionary object in the class BoggleGame.

Let's say you made sth like this :

class BoggleGame{

private:
    Dictionary dico;

}

In this case, there will be a compile error if the constructor Dictionary::Dictionary() doesn't exist.

So I think, the solution of your problem should be to either :

- Declare a constructor with no parameter in the Dictionary class
- Declare dico as pointer (that's mean Dictionary * dico)

But it's would be better if you post your code.

Comment: yes that would solve my compile error but it wouldn't be beneficial to my problem as i've already created a dictionary object in the main that i'm passing into the constructor for BoggleGame.

Comment: In this case, just create a default constructor of Dictionary with no body and leave it like this.

Comment: ok that seems to fix my compile error now to see if it does what i want it to (or at least something close to it)